# Refused Georgian Visa application

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, applications, georgia-country, nigerian-citizens

I applied for a Georgian visa at the embassy and I was denied. I don't understand why it was denied, but I got my file from them saying this statement. I am from Nigeria and studying an MBA Program in Malaysia. I don't know if I should appeal or just forget about it.

[image]

Comment: @JSpinners There’s nothing you can do unless you want to pay an Immigration lawyer.

Comment: I read your reply and i haven't been there before and it's my first application. I don't have any illegal history

Comment: Just confused why they would say that, cause if my application is not right. Then i would say something is wrong, but saying that i would be a threat to national society isnt right, cause i don't have any and how do they know that.

Comment: It could be related to your US ban for passport-related misrepresentation https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119825/212a6ci-material-misrepresentation or your two previous Schengen refusals https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119827/can-i-apply-for-a-uk-visit-visa-as-a-foreign-student-in-malaysia

Comment: I don't think so, cause Australia didn't say anything about this.

Comment: @Traveller your personal circumstances in your home country and or country of usual residence, which might encourage you to remain in Australia at the end of your proposed visit, such as your current employment situation, employment prospects, business, property and or family ties The reasonableness of your trip, taking into account your stated purpose of visit, your intended activities, your contacts in Australia and your proposed length of stay in Australia

Comment: @Traveller Your financial situation eg insufficient funds to cover your proposed stay in Australia, irregular transaction history and or unverifiable source of funds
Your limited history of travel to countries that have a similar socio-economic standing to Australia. nothing about been endanger to the state security. I don't know why didn't say that to me. No vfs scan and stay found say i am state security.

Comment: We do not have answers for you. Anything you hear here will be conjecture. Overall however it seems you have poor credibility and success rate applying for visas to other countries. You may want to stop applying and get a lawyer to look at your applications. You have been applying left, right, center to various countries and falling flat.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of a question about Schengen? Georgia isn't in Schengen. The Schengen question is clearly related, and it's good to make the asker aware of it. But it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @David Richerby. I asked myself the same thing. I got my response from Uk and it was different from this Georgia. It's just not right to be honest. I made a mistake and i accept that, but saying something on my application and not my record.. It's not nice to me. I don't even care about that, cause i would safe me some cash. Uk give me a good reason and i was happy about it.